# Programatically video capture a window of a separate program on Windows, Linux or Mac

Tags: linux, macos, window, video-capture, video-encoding

Is there a way in any language for Windows, Linux or Mac (I'll use whatever OS is easiest) to programatically screen cap a different program's window?

Also programatically recording a specific box on the screen would be acceptable if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's generally possible on all of those OSs; the details are OS-specific, of course, and it's not exactly trivial on any of them. There are commercial or freeware tools for all OSs that do it. On Linux, you could just use, for example, [Xvidcap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: but is that programatically controllable?

Comment: You could certainly launch it from your program, yes. I know you're looking for an API to do this, but as I said, it's not trivial -- no OS has a "captureMovieFromRectangle()" call that I'm aware of. Since xvidcap is open-source, you could study its code to learn how it's done on Linux.